# How to increment session variable in mule ESB?

Tags: mule, session-variables

I have a requirement like first two messages need to be routed into one direction next three into another direction after some other root. I came to know that session variable scope and lifetime will be throughout the session. so i tried like

## [sessionVars.count+1]

but getting concatenated value instead addition. initial count value is 0 and i'm running on mule 3.8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First initialize your session variable

```
<set-session-variable variableName="count" value="#[0]"/>
```

To increment it

```
<set-session-variable variableName="count" value="#[sessionVars.count + 1]"/>
```